# On package delete whether the EA_OnPreDeleteElement event is triggred

Tags: enterprise-architect

When an package is deleted  "EA_OnPreDeletePackage" event is triggered.If a package contains an element with package the elements is also deleted so why the   EA_OnPreDeleteElement event is not triggred. So how can we find the what elements are getting  deleted when an package is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Just look which elements are inside the package when you receive the `EA_OnPreDeletePackage` event. It makes absolutely no sense to send the event for all elements.